# IntelliJ says "Warning: java: foo/bar/Baz.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations", but it doesn't say in which line it is referring to

Tags: intellij-idea, warnings, compiler-warnings, javac, unchecked

I am getting this warning:

[image: ScreenShot]

When I click on the image, it just opens the associated Editor, but it doesn't say the line number where the warning is raised.
I don't want to add `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` on the whole class...

Any workaround/fix?

Comment: The warnings in the corresponding editor should navigate you to the problematic lines.

Comment: It doesn't. The editor is opened and the cursor is positioned on the first line. I think, it may be a limit on the javac compiler (so IntelliJ is unable to parse the message since the line number may be missing from the javac compiler). Eclipse uses its own compiler, which raises different warnings, but those warning are always including the line numbers.

Comment: Right, it will open on the first line, but on the right you should see the list of all warnings in corresponding editor (small yellow dots). There is also summary indicator (a green/yellow/red square in top right corner of the editor) which indicates overall 'health' of the editor. This should not be green for your case

Comment: like this: http://s9.postimage.org/4km1mlufz/image.png

Comment: @denisk it shows it green to me, and there is no sign on the bar

Comment: Does your project has language level at 5.0+ (Project Structure -> Project)? Do you have 'Unchecked Warning' inspection enabled and its severity level set to either Warning or Error (Settings -> Inspections -> General -> Unchecked Warning) ?

Comment: I have Language Level 6.0 and the inspection related to "Unchecked Warning" is selected. Using IntelliJ 12.0.1

Comment: It is probably a bug in the "Unchecked Warning" inspection of IntelliJ IDEA.  As far as I can tell, the inspection is supposed to catch this warning, but it does not. It is happening to me too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why your IDE does not show you generic warnings, but you can try to compile with

```
-Xlint:unchecked
```

to get more details.

Comment: thanks denisk, I'll try that. that's so obvious since it's what is suggested in the messages, but probably I would never thought that by myself. BTW, I think it will disable those warnings. I'll try it anyway and let you know. Thanks, and have a great day.

Comment: What does it mean to compile with `-Xlint:unchecked`.  Are you talking about command line or IDE setting?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky You can provide compile options in IDE's Run Configuration, as well as in command line.

Answer (score 72):

To compile with `-Xlint:unchecked` in IntelliJ IDEA:

- Go to `Settings` dialog (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd> +<kbd>,</kbd> )
- Select `Compiler` > `Java Compiler`
- Add following into the field `Additional command line parameters`:

  `-Xlint:unchecked`
- Run your compile again

Comment: Thank you so much for giving explicit instructions.  I looked everywhere for detailed steps and your comment was the only one that explained HOW.  Intellij has so many options; it's hard to find things.

Comment: On OSX versions of IntelliJ, the Settings Dialog is at `Cmd`+`,`

Comment: I wish this was available in Android Studio.

Comment: In recent versions (I'm looking at IntelliJ 2018.1), the settings page is now "Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler".

Answer (score 4):

#### IntelliJ IDEA 15

A faster solution:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>
- Type "Additional com" and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

  [image: Additional command line parameters]
- Type `-Xlint:unchecked` > OK

  [image: Xlint unchecked]
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> to recompile (or go to Build > Compile ... )

  - you can select a class / module from the project tree to specify what you want to be recompiled
- You will see the line and the column where the problem appeared

  E.g.: Warning:(**5**,**27**) java: unchecked ...

Comment: Or on Mac - [CMD] [Shift] [A]